# Google Maps API v2: How to make markers clickable?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How to I make the markers in Android Google Maps API v2 become clickable so they will either bring up a menu with options or just start a new activity? I believe I made the markers in my app currently in a "newb" method. I didn't assign them a name or a method to be able to link it in with the rest of the required code.

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title("My Spot")
        .snippet("This is my spot!")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

If you ANSWER this, please include a sample code of a marker being introduced with a unique name and then being set as clickable to open a new activity.

Comment: Here is official manual: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#associate_data_with_a_marker

Answer (score 252, accepted):

All markers in Google Android Maps Api v2 are clickable. You don't need to set any additional properties to your marker.
What you need to do - is to register marker click callback to your googleMap and handle click within callback:

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
    implements OnMarkerClickListener
{
    private Marker myMarker;    

    private void setUpMap()
    {
        .......
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("My Spot")
                    .snippet("This is my spot!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        ......
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
        {
            //handle click here
        }
    }
}
```

here is a good [guide on google about marker customization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)

Comment: Is there a way to listen for clicks on the popup window? The one that displays your title/snippet?

Comment: the same thing as with markers - you need to register `OnInfoWindowClickListenerCallback`. There is a method in GoogleMap for that: `googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(listener);`

Comment: It is all working very fine for now, I noticed my mistake was not setting it as a variable earlier in the code. I simply forgot the ";" and the implemented code

Comment: How can I add a custom layout to each marker that is clicked?

Comment: Please, why

if (marker.equals(myMarker)) {....}
? If the routine passes you the correct marker, why do you need to check which marker?

Comment: @JDOaktown you need this check if you have different logic for different markers. Lets say you want to show a toast only when specific marker is clicked. If you have the same handling logic for all your markers - you dont need to check marker

Comment: As mentioned in documentation (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener), you need to return true if click was consumed. If you return false - default behavior will occur

Answer (score 51):

`setTag(position)` while adding marker to map.

```
Marker marker =  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
marker.setTag(position);
```

`getTag()` on `setOnMarkerClickListener` listener

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    int position = (int)(marker.getTag());
                   //Using position get Value from arraylist 
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

Avoid using Activity implements OnMarkerClickListener, use a local OnMarkerClickListener

```
// Not a good idea
class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMarkerClickListener {
}
```

You will need a map to lookup the original data model linked to the marker

```
private Map<Marker, Map<String, Object>> markers = new HashMap<>();
```

You will need a data model

```
private Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
```

Put some data in the data model

```
dataModel.put("title", "My Spot");
dataModel.put("snipet", "This is my spot!");
dataModel.put("latitude", 20.0f);
dataModel.put("longitude", 100.0f);
```

When creating a new marker using a data model add both to the maker map

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markers.put(marker, dataModel);
```

For on click marker event, use a local OnMarkerClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // grab for laters
    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Map dataModel = (Map)markers.get(marker);
            String title = (String)dataModel.get("title");
            markerOnClick(title);

            return false;
        }
    });

    mapView.onResume();

    showMarkers();

    ZoomAsync zoomAsync = new ZoomAsync();
    zoomAsync.execute();
}
```

For displaying the info window retrieve the original data model from the marker map:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Map dataModel = (Map)markers.get(marker);
            String title = (String)dataModel.get("title");

            infoWindowOnClick(title);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are the drawbacks of implementing OnMarkerClickListener?

Comment: @D.Rosado OnMarkerClickListener is for when the marker is clicked, OnInfoWindowClickListener is when the info window is clicked.  Am I misunderstanding your question?  Implement each inline to keep the implementation inside the same code as the setter.

Answer (score 3):

Another Solution : you get the marker by its title

```
public class MarkerDemoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener
{
      private Marker myMarker;    

      private void setUpMap()
      {
      .......
      googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

      myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(latLng)
                  .title("My Spot")
                  .snippet("This is my spot!")
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
      ......
      }

  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) 
  {

     String name= marker.getTitle();

      if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("My Spot")) 
      {
          //write your code here
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my whole code of a map activity with 4 clickable markers. Click on a marker shows an info window, and after click on info window you are going to another activity: English, German, Spanish or Italian. If you want to use OnMarkerClickListener in spite of OnInfoWindowClickListener, you just have to swap this line:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
```

to this:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
```

this line:

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0)
```

to this:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0)
```

and at the end of the method "onMarkerClick":

```
return true;
```

I think it may be helpful for someone ;)

```
package pl.pollub.translator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Choose a language.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                if(arg0 != null && arg0.getTitle().equals("English")){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, English.class);
                startActivity(intent1);}

                if(arg0 != null && arg0.getTitle().equals("German")){
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, German.class);
                startActivity(intent2);} 

                if(arg0 != null && arg0.getTitle().equals("Italian")){
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Italian.class);
                startActivity(intent3);}

                if(arg0 != null && arg0.getTitle().equals("Spanish")){
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Spanish.class);
                startActivity(intent4);}
            }
        });
        LatLng greatBritain = new LatLng(51.30, -0.07);
        LatLng germany = new LatLng(52.3107, 13.2430);
        LatLng italy = new LatLng(41.53, 12.29);
        LatLng spain = new LatLng(40.25, -3.41);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(greatBritain)
                .title("English")
                .snippet("Click on me:)"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(germany)
                .title("German")
                .snippet("Click on me:)"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(italy)
                .title("Italian")
                .snippet("Click on me:)"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(spain)
                .title("Spanish")
                .snippet("Click on me:)"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(greatBritain));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(germany));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(italy));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(spain));
    }
}
```

Comment: return true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur); false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move to the marker and an info window to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Below Kotlin code can help to you

**Create Marker**

```
        for (i in arrayList.indices) {
            val marker = googleMap!!.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(
                    LatLng(
                        arrayList[i].location_latitude!!.toDoubleOrNull()!!,
                        arrayList[i].location_latitude!!.toDoubleOrNull()!!
                    )
                ).title(arrayList[i].business_name)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
            )
            marker.tag = i
        }
```

**Marker Click**

```
        googleMap!!.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on  ${marker.tag}")
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1
public class TopAttractions extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, 
GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener

Step 2
gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

Step 3
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if(marker.getTitle().equals("sharm el-shek"))
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Hamdy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin - Close Marker Clicks**

My answer for closing clickable feature of markers on map.

I found this question when I searched that "**android map marker close clickable**"

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener { true }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);` in the `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` method. So every time you click a marker it displays the text name in the toast method.

```
public class DemoMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    double lat=0.34924212701428;
    double lng=32.616554024713;
    String venue = "Capital Shoppers City";
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(venue)).setTag(0);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location);
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
    mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    // Retrieve the data from the marker.
    Integer clickCount = (Integer) marker.getTag();

    // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
    if (clickCount != null) {
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
        marker.setTag(clickCount);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                       marker.getTitle() +
                       " has been clicked ",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
    // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
    // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
    return false;
}
```

}

You can check this link for reference
[Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)

Answer (score -4):

**I have edited the given above example...**

```
public class YourActivity extends implements OnMarkerClickListener
{
    ......

    private void setMarker()
    {
        .......
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("My Spot")
                    .snippet("This is my spot!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        ......
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

       Toast.makeText(this,marker.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```