# Google Maps API v2: How to add OnMarkerClickListener OR OnInfoWindowClickListener to start a new activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My current code

```
package com.crusaders.epeats;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener{

private Marker myMarkerOne;
private Marker myMarkerTwo;
private Marker myMarkerThree;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_display);
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-33.796923, 150.922433);
    LatLng latLngTwo = new LatLng(-33.101010, 150.101012);
    LatLng latLngThree = new LatLng(26.123456, 178.123456);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        myMarkerOne = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("myMarkerOne")
            .snippet("myMarkerOne InfoWindow")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)))
        myMarkerTwo = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLngTwo)
            .title("myMarkerTwo") 
            .snippet("myMarkerTwo InfoWindow")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        myMarkerThree = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLngThree)
            .title("myMarkerThree")
            .snippet("myMarkerThree InfoWindow")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));   
}
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (marker.equals(myMarkerOne))
    {
    setContentView(R.layout.viewone);
    }
    else if (marker.equals(myMarkerTwo))
    {
    setContentView(R.layout.viewtwo);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I need to set up multiple markers to open different XML layouts on click. It can be done either with `OnMarkerClick` or `OnInfoWindow` click. I set the first marker to open or set contentview.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226453/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable) was useful for me but I probably wrote it in wrong.

else if statement was a test but it doesn't work cause second marker won't start. If you can help answer this please include sample code and a method to make it return back to the map if I hit the back button.

Comment: It should be written like this  if (marker.equals("myMarkerOne")), do you want to open xml layout??

Comment: Yes a xml. My problem is the else if statement being improperly used.

Comment: you need another activity file to show your xml, otherwise it will replace your current layout..

Comment: see [this](http://www.java-examples.com/if-else-if-statement-example) for if else statement

Comment: Therefore I will use intent and all that fun stuff to launch a new activity? How about hitting the back button, will it go back an activity?