# How to use OnMarkerClickListener to get location of that marker?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map with 3 options. A search function, a nearby locations function, and a click on the map to set marker option. I want to save these locations in my Parse backend, but the only one I was able to figure out how to do is the set marker option.

When I do a nearby search and get a bunch of results I want to be able to click on one of the markers (see the title and location) and then click on the save button to save to my backend. Here's what I have:

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

        // Clears all the existing markers
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            final String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            final String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);


            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        }

    }
```

I have tried to add setOnMarkerClickListener, but it ends up not showing me anything (right now I at least get the title and location).

I know how to save the location to my backend but I'm not sure how to get the location of the clicked marker.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226453/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the onMarkerClickListener for your map object, the callback returns to you the [Marker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html) object. 
Marker has an attribute called Position which has the LatLng value that you require. Also you have to add a infoWindow, using the details the Marker object has to display name and other details.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    LatLng markerLocation=marker.getPosition();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly! Didn't know about the getPosition attribute. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!