# Android: Make the marker as unclickable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi I'm creating the marker like

```
Marker thisUserMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(new LatLng(CURRENT_LAT, CURRENT_LNG))
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_marker_current_location)));
```

after this i want to make the marker as unclickable, according to the CURRENT_LAT and CURRENT_LNG. Is it possible to do that

Comment: what  do you mean by *marker as unclickable*?

Comment: you mean to say that user cant click on marker?

Comment: @Jaydip Umaretiya: Yes

Comment: You can see bellow there is two answer you can use that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this workaround, return true when you click on a `marker`

```
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Other posibility could be implement `implements OnMarkerClickListener` and in your `onMarkerClick()` compare it with the marker that you don't want to be clickable and do nothing.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

You can also check this question : [`google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226453/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable)

Comment: @Blackbelt Misstyped.

Comment: It does because instead of put `getText()` or something about `marker` it shows nothing as the OP wants... well at least it worked for me on my old project...

Answer (score 1):

set Clickable like this.

```
     MarkerOptions marker=new MarkerOptions().position(resto).title(getAddress(28.6200, 77.2100));
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
    map.addMarker(marker);

   map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if(marker.getTitle().equals(getAddress(28.6200, 77.2100))){
                Log.e("Delhi","Delhi");
                Log.e("Destance",""+distance(resto.latitude,resto.longitude,Delhi1.latitude,Delhi1.longitude,"M"));

            }else if(marker.getTitle().equals("Marker in Delhi1")){
                Log.e("Delhi1","Delhi1");

            }
                return false;

        }
    });
```

**GetAddress metgod()**

```
   public String getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    String Address=" ";
    Log.e("ADDRESS","ADDRESS");
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        Address= obj.getAddressLine(0);

        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.e("IGA", "Address" + add);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return Address;
}
```

Comment: For getAddress i'm getting "The method getAddress(double, double) is undefined for the type new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){}"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override the ClickListener. Im not sure if the lat and lng values are saved in the Marker arg0 event.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Hope it helps.