# How do I show place details?

Tags: java, android

So I have a class called 'InterestingPoint' with variables 'Name', 'Coordinates'. I've created a list with interesting places and then I've added markers on the map like that:

```
for (InterestingPoint point:route.points_of_interest){
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point.Coordinates).title(point.Name));
    }
```

So the main question is can I get details of any marker when I click on it? When I click on marker I want to show description and picture of that place.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226453/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to set OnMarkerClickListener in `onCreate` method.

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

Then you override the `onMarkerClick` method to get the title and position of the `Marker`.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    String title = marker.getTitle();
    LatLng position = marker.getPosition();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot. But how do I show more details of that marker? F.e. show picture of that place or show description?

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. I think you should implement `getPicture` and `getDescription` method in `InterestingPoint` class.