# android: not getting info on marker click

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have four entries in database, I'm fetching all data using retrofit. API is working fine I'm getting all necessary data. I want to show users name, address, number and skills (Coming from database) on marker click and set them in custom alert dialog.

**Issue**

When I click on any marker I am getting only last entry. Mean on each marker `infoWindowClickListener` I am only getting same name, address, number and skills every time.
I also save index with marker but I don’t know how to work with that index.

**What I want?**

Each marker should display its own info.
Anyone can help me what should I do inside `onInfoWindowClickListener` method to get the exact info associated with each marker.
Please feel free to ask anything if you don’t understand well.

MapFragment.java:

```
 public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap mMap) {
        mGoogleMap = mMap;
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        fetchLastLocation();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        ApiInterface apiInterface2 = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<AllDataResponse> call2 = apiInterface2.allLabours("showAds");
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<AllDataResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllDataResponse> call, Response<AllDataResponse> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {

                    if (response.body().isError_bol()) {
                        String errosr = response.body().getError_message();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errosr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        labourDataAlls = response.body().getAll_labours();

                        if (labourDataAlls != null) {
                            latLngData.addAll(labourDataAlls);
                            Log.v("TAaG", "LOGS" + latLngData.size());

                            for (int i = 0; i < latLngData.size(); i++) {
                                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latLngData.get(i).getLb_latitude());
                                double lng = Double.parseDouble(latLngData.get(i).getLb_longitude());
                                Str_lb_name = latLngData.get(i).getLb_name();
                                Str_lb_phone = latLngData.get(i).getLb_phone();
                                Str_lb_address = latLngData.get(i).getLb_address();
                                Str_lb_skill = latLngData.get(i).getLb_skills();
                               drawMarker(new LatLng(lat, lng), i);
  }

                            Log.d("setr", String.valueOf(list));
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unknown Error Occurs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    
        private void drawMarker(final LatLng point , final int index){
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(point).title(labourDataAlls.get(index).getLb_name()+index);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

setTag(index) while adding marker to googleMap

```
private void drawMarker(final LatLng point , final int index){
    private Marker marker;
    marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point)
            .title(labourDataAlls.get(index).getLb_name()+index);
    marker.setTag(index);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    int index = (int)(marker.getTag());
    //Use index get Value from labourDataAlls
}
```

reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962580/12676247

Comment: On the basis of this index can I show labour_skill in toast?
in OnWindowInfoClickListener